# How to authorize Android which won't load the Android OS?

Tags: android, adb

My Android won't boot, it's stuck in the start-boot-loading   screen  because  I've deleted something accidentally. So I'm trying to recover it. However, it's always:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
aabbccdd    unauthorized
```

I've tried restarting the adb server and deleting the folder ~/.android but it didn't help. In Android Studio it says "press authorize on your device" when I connect my devise and try to run an application but how can I press it if the Android OS hasn't even been loaded?

And the same error:

```
$ adb reboot bootloader
error: device unauthorized.
This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

update:

after enterying the recover mode, I end up with the same thing:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
0123456789ABCDEF        no permissions
```

Comment: Will it boot into recovery mode?  The way you do this is different with every phone/tablet but often it's holding down one of the volume keys and then the power key to turn it on.

Comment: `unauthorized` and `no permissions` are 2 separate issues. The latter can be easily solver with proper `udev` rule.

Comment: @AlexP., whatever.

Answer (score -1):

In recovery there should be an option to "apply update from adb", that should make you be able to adb sideload the stock ROM and get you going, remember, after you sideload you have to factory reset otherwise you'd be stuck in a bootloop. To adb sideload, do this "adb sideload nameoftheziporimg".